# Word for nemesis that does not refer to a person

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there was a word that meant nearly the same thing as nemesis, but was not connotated with a person.

For example, if someone were to say: "Your greatest nemesis showed you your deepest fear."

Most people would assume nemesis was actually referring to a person, but in this context, the author was trying to refer to an abiotic thing. (ex: anger, drugs, acid rain)

**So what is a word that means the same as nemesis, but does not refer to a person?**

Also: The author cannot explicitly state what the `nemesis replacement word` refers to in the sentence, the reader must 'fill in the blank' with what the word means to them.

**EDIT**: Here is the exact sentence I am writing:

*The relationship between you and your [nemesis] may seem to be purely an unmutual fight, but underneath the surface, your [nemesis] fuels you to greater heights.*

but, in this case, I do not want your nemesis to refer to a person necessarily, I want it to refer to a deep struggle that you might have.

**EDIT 2**: Due to popular demand, I have changed the phrase *purely an unmutual fight* to *strictly a fight with no benefits*, the sentence now reads:

*The relationship between you and your [nemesis] may seem to be strictly a fight with no benefits, but underneath the surface, your [nemesis] fuels you to greater heights.*

Comment: It would be helpful to have an example of a sentence that uses the word you are looking for in the manner you wish it to be used, without using "nemesis." BladorthinTheGrey's answer seems like a good bet, but you seem to have very specific ways you want the word to be used, which requires possibly multiple examples.

Comment: Any dictionary will inform you that *nemesis* does not necessarily imply a person. However, it does in educated use imply the agent or agency of *deserved* punishment or revenge.

Comment: "_Most people would assume nemesis was actually referring to a person..._" Why? I wouldn't jump to such a conclusion, and I asked a few people around here, and none would assume it means a person.

Comment: What is an ‘unmutual fight’? A one-sided one? A fight heavily in one party's favour? Just one side punching the other?

Comment: That is a good point... It seemed logical at the time, I meant a fight that has no benefits

Comment: why not just enemy

Comment: Nemesis is also [the name of a star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_(hypothetical_star)) which could explain mass extinctions but more probably doesn't even exist.

Comment: You're saying the whale was not Ahab's nemesis?

Comment: "A foolish consistency is the *hobgoblin* of little minds." --Ralph Waldo Emerson

Comment: Nemesis is fine. The word you want to replace is "unmutual".

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> ### Bane
>
> **noun**
>
> 1. a person or thing that ruins or spoils:
>      *Gambling was the bane of his existence.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bane))

Your **bane** goes beyond just ruining you; it is your nemesis, it is always getting you and you fall victim to it very often.

Comment: I'm not sure I've heard "bane" used outside of the phrase "bane of someone's existence," or without reference to the "nemesis replacement word."

Comment: @KatherineLockwood I agree with you, generally, *bane* is used in the phrases *bane of my life* etc.

Comment: +1; I think _bane_ is bang on. @BladorthinTheGrey, I see you are on a roll!

Comment: Bane works well in the context, but as @Katherine Lockwood's comment said, I barely ever here it used outside of the phrase "bane of someone's existence." I was hoping for a more commonly used word, but still, bane works well.

I will select your answer after I am surer that there isn't a more common solution.

Comment: for the particular phrase in question, it doesn't really fit, but for the question asked in general, it's spot on.

Comment: In the Legend of Zelda, the Master Sword is occasionally referred to by the "Blade of Evil's Bane."

Comment: *The relationship between you and the bane of your existence... your bane fuels you....* The OP should use the word and the idiom for that sentence.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood - [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bane+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBane%20of%3B%2Cc0) returns many results too other than just "Bane of my existence", FYI ...and I *thought* that word sounded familiar...

Comment: Considering the doubts in comments here, I just wanted to say that *bane* was exactly what I was thinking when I saw this question in the HNQs.

Comment: Though not so often in common parlance, `bane` is quite often used in phrases other than "... of one's existence/life" in literature.  Tolkien used it frequently, for example; "Isildur's Bane" is one of the names of the One Ring.

Comment: I don't really agree with this one. A bane is one's undoing. A nemesis is an constant enemy, one you are in a tug war with, and constantly challenged by. A bane kills or destroys you. I definitely get a sense that a bane is only defined after it has destroyed a person, and is therefore not the same as an unpersonified nemesis.

Comment: If it were true that a bane is only defined after it has destroyed a person, then no one could truthfully utter the phrase "[it] is the bane of my existence".  Per the definition above, "bane" can be used to refer to things which generally ruin or spoil, but have not specifically ruined or spoiled yet.

Answer (score 42):

There's no reason you can't use **nemesis**. [Merriam Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nemesis) definition page gives several examples where the word "nemesis" doesn't refer to people:

> On just the kind of putt that had been a career-long nemesis, he kept his head perfectly still and knocked the ball squarely in the hole. —Jaime Diaz, Sports Illustrated, 20 Feb. 1995 (from M-W)
>
> Thus, once surgeons implant the new graft, tissue rejection—the unforgiving nemesis of most transplant attempts—occurs in only 3% to 5% of cases. —Christine Gorman et al., Time, 7 Dec. 1987 (from M-W)

Granted, these sentences all refer to the thing that is the nemesis, but this seems a natural thing to do in order not to keep the reader/listener hanging. Your example sentence, "Your greatest nemesis showed you your deepest fear," assumes that the reader/listener already has some idea what that nemesis is.

Comment: A well-put sentence drives the reader to the intended conclusion. Yes, nemesis can refer to things other than people, but more often than not, it refers to a person. Making the word `nemesis` more likely to give the reader a different conclusion than the intended one.  However, your answer does have good reason, so you get an upvote from me.

Comment: @Pythogen I see no problem using "nemesis".  You're already anthropomorphizing this concept in your example sentence by describing the relationship as a "fight".

Answer (score 21):

You might use **bête noire** for this. In the context of your example it most often would *be* your greatest fear, but I think you could use it to say that the *acknowledged* bête noire showed you your *actual*, unacknowledged deepest fear. From [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%AAte_noire):

> Etymology
>   Borrowing from French bête noire ‎(literally “black beast”).
>
> **Noun**
>   bête noire ‎(plural bêtes noires)
>
> An anathema; someone or something which is particularly disliked or
>   avoided; an object of aversion, the bane of one’s existence.

It is used for the kind of things you mention:

> Several of the rules cautioned against Seneca's **bête noire, anger**.
>   —[Richard Brookhiser, *Founding Father*](https://books.google.com/books?id=s3PTediy5mkC&lpg=PA128&ots=b5ONADSlRm&dq=%22seneca's%20bete%20noire%2C%20anger%22&pg=PA128#v=onepage&q=%22seneca's%20bete%20noire,%20anger%22&f=false)
>
> But Ecstasy quickly became a class A **drug** and was soon seen as the
>   **bête noire** of club life. —[Mike Presdee, *Cultural Criminology and the Carnival of Crime*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cAWDAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA125&ots=F2jh_YbGn0&dq=drugs%20b%C3%AAte%20noire&pg=PA125#v=onepage&q=drugs%20b%C3%AAte%20noire&f=false)
>
> For years, the public and scientists alike feared that lakes and
>   forests in the eastern United States were being destroyed by acid rain
>   . . . . Today, environmental issues are far different from those even
>   30 years ago. In part, that's because visible pollution has almost
>   disappeared—the plumes from power plants are mostly steam (and
>   **carbon dioxide, today's bête noire**, is invisible). —[Richard L. Stroup, *Eco-nomics: What Everyone Should Know about Economics and the
>   Environment*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KR3aDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA5&dq=%22b%C3%AAte%20noire%22%20%22acid%20rain%22%20-neurath&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q=%22b%C3%AAte%20noire%22%20%22acid%20rain%22%20-neurath&f=false)

I think it's especially useful for personifying/demonizing a more abstract concept (that doesn't actually care oone way or the other about you) as an adversary. So your example would read:

> *The relationship between you and your **bête noire** may seem to be purely an unmutual fight, but underneath the surface, your **bête
>   noire** fuels you to greater heights.*

(Wiktionary also suggests the similar [**bugbear**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bugbear#English).)

Answer (score 19):

You might consider ***kryptonite*** if the circumstances allow for it.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kryptonite) defines it as:

> [mass noun] (in science fiction) an alien mineral with the property of depriving Superman of his powers

The book [*From Average to Awesome: Lessons for Living an Extraordinary Life*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wgeyM3AEl3MC&pg=PA226&dq=%22his+kryptonite%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEhpPasdvQAhWCsVQKHT9qDiEQ6AEIOzAG#v=onepage&q=%22his%20kryptonite%22&f=false)
By Jim Smith, Jr. uses it like this:

> Bronwen, a close friend, recently told me about how her friend Denny summoned the courage to get rid of his kryptonite. She related how his sales job was causing him severe pain....

Comment: You stole my answer.  Here, take an up vote. :)

Comment: See also the song ["Kryptonite" by Three Doors Down.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPU8OAjjS4k)

Answer (score 14):

I suggest **demon** for this.

Unless there is likelihood of confusion of this figurative use with a literal use (think horns), I think it would fit well in your phrase due to it having the right 'weight'.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with the classic Herman Melville concept of **White Whale**. It might be a little too much in the direction of a plain obsession, which is not the same as a nemesis. But it seems to define a struggle against a specific thing or being, and a tug war between two adversaries. Adversary is also a good word, but I personally think that refers more to a person again.

Answer (score 3):

> **bugaboo**
>   plural bugaboos
>   1:  an imaginary object of fear
>   2:  bugbear 2; also :  something that causes fear or distress out of proportion to its importance

Comment: Why do you feel this answers the question? Answers should provide explanation and context, and be mostly your own words.

Comment: "The relationship between you and your bugaboo may seem to be purely an unmutual fight, but underneath the surface, your bugaboo fuels you to greater heights."

Comment: I'm laughing too hard right now

Answer (score 3):

[**Inner Demons**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Inner%20Demons)

> **noun**
>
> Personal struggles in your mind, almost always a solo fight

"The relationship between you and your inner demons may seem to be purely an unmutual fight, but underneath the surface, your inner demons fuels you to greater heights."

Also, just a suggestion, instead of repeating the word in both places, why not write a pronoun for it in the second sentence?

[Urban Dictionary]

Answer (score 2):

One's ***curse*** implies the same as *nemesis* without a connotation of a person. Check the relevant examples using *curse* in this context (from ODO) below.

> The relationship between you and your ***curse*** may seem to be purely
>   an unmutual fight, but underneath the surface, your ***curse*** fuels
>   you to greater heights.

ODO:

> **[curse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/curse)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.1** [usually in singular] A cause of harm or misery
>
> ‘Some people were afflicted with the curse of bad timing.’
>
> ‘But for five years he went into a colossal sulk, blaming his problems
>   on ‘the curse of being lower middle class’ and refusing to give
>   interviews.’

Answer (score 1):

[**NIGHTMARE**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nightmare) can also be a good option,*meaning a person, thing, or situation that is very difficult to deal with.*

Answer (score 0):

Although tending toward too generic, perhaps, *obstruction* seems to fit, while not suggesting human qualities.

**EDITED / EXPANDED ANSWER:**

I voted up *bane* and *bête noire* because most writers in most contexts would likely choose these as forceful and compelling alternatives to "nemesis".  They meet the OP's requirement of being de-personalized, and are simply more catchy to most readers.

Still, while *obstruction* may seem bland or generic (as acknowledged in my first answer), it has a justification supported in *[The Book of Doing and Being: Rediscovering Creativity in Life, Love, and Work](https://books.google.com/books?id=gk4RCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA82)* — which describes *obstruction* in the very sense I meant it.

Excerpts:

> Obstruction often comes up in opposition to the things that we **most want to create and most want to do**. . . According to the *Oxford American Dictionary*, obstruction is "a thing that impedes or prevents passage or progress; an obstacle or blockage." . . . With enough repetition, an obstruction easily turns into full-blown self-sabotage. . . Now it is time to dialogue with ***your obstruction***.  Finding out what it has to tell you will free up your reservoir of creative energy. [Emphasis mine.]

(By the aptly named Barnet **Bain**!)

Note that the phrase *"your [nemesis/obstruction/bane]"* appears in the OP's example sentence.

The OP also gave examples of anger, drugs, and acid rain as fitting this descriptor.  The *internal state of anger* definitely seems to qualify as an "obstruction" — existing as part of one's own self, and less malevolent than "bane" (that which ruins or spoils) or "bête noire" (literally 'black beast' in French.)

Obstructions are an unavoidable fact of life, not necessarily evil or "out to get us" — human qualities we are trying to avoid in this use case.  They also spur growth and adaptation, capable of fueling us "to greater heights".  The derived word "obstructionism" is often used in political discussions, and while obstructionism can be maddening to witness, it doesn't *necessarily imply* that the opposing party is diabolical, a "black beast", or the bringer of downfall.  We can choose a neutral (or at least [more nuanced](https://books.google.com/books?id=w-mNBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA4&dq=%22more%20nuanced%20view%22&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=%22more%20nuanced%20view%22&f=false)) view of our obstructions.

> The relationship between you and your obstruction may seem to be strictly a fight with no benefits, but underneath the surface, your obstruction fuels you to greater heights.

Comment: I learned to consider my possible answer more carefully, or comment first rather than answer.